# Implementing vote escrow with multiple positions and non-linear decay

Tags: solidity, defi, curve, escrow

I want to do vote escrow. I know that Curve is the most popular implementation. My problem with it is I want to allow multiple positions and a non-linear decay.

I'd like to not write from scratch. Ideally, I'd find a different “lego block” that would help me solve the above issues. Can you recommend an implementation that does this?

Many thanks!